# Пропадает Яндекс карта

Tags: javascript, php, яндекс-карты

при обновлении страницы пропадает Яндекс карта

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript" ></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
 ymaps.ready(init);
 function init() {
   var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
     center: [<?php echo $object['point']; ?>],
     zoom: 16
   }, {
     searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
   });
  
   var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(); 
  
   // Добавим метку красного цвета.
   var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([
     <?php echo $object['point']; ?>
   ], {
     balloonContent: '<?php echo $object['adres']; ?>'
   }, {
     preset: 'islands#icon',
     iconColor: '#ff0000'
   });
   myCollection.add(myPlacemark);
  
   myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: `<?php echo` можно сократить до `<?=`

Answer (score 0):

Вы не передаете api-ключ, вероятно, проблема в этом. Его следует получить в [ЛК Разработчика](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/services/), а затем подключать как-то вот так:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
```

Если проблема все-таки не в этом, то скорее всего, ее причина не в этом куске кода, а где-то еще.